# How do I assign the "Key Vault Secrets User" RBAC role on Key Vault creation via ARM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, rbac

I'm attempting to deploy a new suite of resources via ARM using a DevOps YAML pipeline, and so far everything is going great... Apart from the important bit - managing secrets in Azure Key Vault.

There are a few stipulations about this pipeline:

1. The Key Vault must be created via ARM template (done)
2. The ARM template needs to store secrets in the new Key Vault (done - I think, can't check)
3. The ARM template should assign the "Key Vault Secrets User" role to the Service Principle (on the new Key Vault) so that...
4. The YAML pipeline (Service Principle) can gain access to the new secrets

Am I right in thinking that during creation of a Key Vault - the ARM template has full access to it, and can therefore assign these RBAC roles?
I think I'm just not sure how to achieve it.

Here's the section of the ARM template that describes creation and key insertion:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01-preview",
        "name": "[variables('keyVaultName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
        "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "family": "A",
                "name": "Standard"
            },
            "tenantId": "<<SOME TENANTID>>",
            "accessPolicies": [],
            "enabledForDeployment": false,
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
            "enableSoftDelete": true,
            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
            "enableRbacAuthorization": true,
            "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', variables('keyVaultName'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
        "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
        "name": "[concat(variables('keyVaultName'), '/apiKey')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "value": "<<SOME API KEY >>"
        }
    },
```

Comment: See Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/roleassignments?tabs=json

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the template...  First the roleDefinitionId:

```
"variables": {
    "KeyVaultSecretsUser": "4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6"
}
```

Then the roleAssignment itself.

re: the `principalId`, not sure what you want there.  If you want the `principalId` of the user (or service principal) that is deploying the template, you have to pass that in as a param, there's no way to retrieve it via the template language - so change that property as appropriate.  If the principal is not a service principal (a group or a user) change the `principalType` property as well.

Also, if you need to change the `principalId` also update the `name` property on the roleAssignment so the `guid()` maintains the idempotent seed.

```
        {
            "scope": "[format('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{0}', variables('keyVaultName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[guid(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName')), parameters('principalId'), variables('KeyVaultSecretsUser'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('KeyVaultSecretsUser')]",
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
            }
        }
```